# Filtrar datos en DatagridView, seleccionando el filtro desde CheckBox, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2010

Estoy intentando filtrar datos en el `DataGridview` con los datos ya cargados, sin necesidad de consultar la base de datos.

Cuando filtro utilizando el `TextBox` lo hago de forma correcta, pero necesito filtrar las opciones con los `CheckBox`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **¿Existe una forma en la que pueda imitar la Clausula `IN` de `SQL` para filtrar los datos pertenecientes la Columna `Tipo`?**. De esta forma : `tipo in('Tipo 1', 'Tipo 2', 'Tipo 3')` algo semejante, de modo que si Marco/Desmarco alguna casilla pueda excluirlo o incluirla en el `IN`

Para Filtrar con el `TextBox` lo hago de esta forma:

```
string nombre_columna = string.Empty; 

private void filtrar_datos(DataGridView datagrid, string nombre_columna, TextBox textbox)
{
     //Crear un DataTable con las Columnas del DataGriview
     DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
     datatable = datagrid.DataSource as DataTable;

     //Crear una vista del DataTable
     DataView vista_datos = new DataView();
     vista_datos = datatable.DefaultView;

     //crear el string del filtro. 
     string filtro = "CONVERT(" + "[" + nombre_columna + "]" + ", System.String) LIKE '%" + textbox.Text.Trim() + "%'";

     //Aplicar el filtro.
     vista_datos.RowFilter = filtro;
}

//Cuando doy click en el Header de cada columna capturo el nombre de la columna.
private void myDataGrid_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 5)
        {
            int indice_columna = e.ColumnIndex;
            nombre_columna = myDataGrid.Columns[indice_columna].DataPropertyName.Trim();
            myTextBox.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
            myTextBox.Enabled = false;
}
```

> Aquí al dar click en el encabezado de la columna obtengo el `DataPropertyName` de la columna para filtrar, y controlo que la columna no sea la `Tipo` para no filtrar con el TextBox esa columna.

Para utilizarlo, en el Evento TextChanged del `TextBox` uso:

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filtrar_datos(myDataGrid, nombre_columna, myTextBox);
}
```

> **¿Cómo puedo filtrar en esa columna `Tipo` utilizando los `CheckBox's`?**

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms) & .NET Netframework 4.

Comment: No se si te entiendo. Si quieres filtrar los datos cuando pulses en uno del los checkbox? Si es asi, usa el evento Checkbox.CheckedChanged, y haz lo mismo que con el textbox

Comment: Vale,no había leido bien tu pregunta. El problema es porque quieres filtrar con varias opciones dependiendo de los checkboxes activados, ahora si entendi :)

Comment: ok lo probaré, pero debo cambiar el filtro de : `"CONVERT(" + "[" + nombre_columna + "]" + ", System.String) LIKE '%" + textbox.Text.Trim() + "%'"`  a `tipo in('Tipo 1','Tipo 3')` cuando se trata de los check

Comment: @Pikoh correcto filtrar por varias opciones, tanto por lo checkbox como por el textbox, pero creo que lo resolveré me surgió otra idea.